# What is the proper way to store yes/no/unknown values for a field?

Tags: c#, boolean

I have a field which might be Yes, No, or Unknown. Should I store it as a nullable boolean? `Nullable<bool>` .. or is it better to create an enum. What is the proper way to do this in C#?

Comment: Considering that an Enum with these exact three states leaves the least space for (mis)interpretation I'd personally go for that option.

Comment: Is there a potential need for other "null-like" values? I.e. you currently have `Unknown` (we don't know the value, presumably) - might there ever be a need for a separate `Not Applicable` (no such value exists) that needs to be distinguished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today you have a field storing Yes / No / Unknown, tomorrow you may have more or less values. `Nullable<bool>` is the less extensive option of the available ones while the `enum` give more expressiveness, is less error prone and can be extended in the future. Use it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "proper way", you can achieve this in at least 5 different ways. But a nullable bool is by far the most expressive for what you have and the shortest involving the least work for you. Use it.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, `NULL` means something else than `unknown`. `NULL` means no entry - `unknown` on the other hand is a deliberate entry. Because of this, I'd use an `enum` with the appropriate values.